# Github Enterprise, Can I change the Template Name of my Repository using Octokit?

Tags: github, octokit.net

I am using Octokit.Net library for GitHub.
I have a repo which was generated from a template repo (Template 1). I have created another template (Template 2) which has my latest changes. I have updated my GitHub repo and made the changes manually and now the GitHub repo matches the changes defined in Template 2.
My GitHub repo still shows "Template 1" in "generated from"
Can I change the generated from text link from Template 1 to Template 2?

Preferences would be do that it with Octokit.Net but I am open for suggestions.
I could not found this option via the UI, so I am thinking, it may not be possible at all.
Deleting and creating the repo is not an option.